# jQuery: placing dialog inside a container

Tags: jquery, dialog

i'd like to use the dialog-widget in modal mode inside a div - is this possible?
so eg. when having  - i'd like to have the obfuscating layer-div (that transparent one) inside that div only, with the status box centered aswell.

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your dialog into a div which stands on top the div you want to make inaccessible.

This div should be hidden initaly, have opacity if you wish, z-index grater than other div's you want to cover.

When showing dialog you should bind onClick event handler on wrapper div which should [prevent bubbling](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) and make wrapper visible. Remove binding and hide wrapper when dialog closes.

Answer (score 0):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

I didn't see anything in the documentation, but you may be able to do this through iframes, or modification of the code base.

And of course, there are alternatives to using jqueryUI for everything:
http://www.designlabelblog.com/2009/03/20-ways-to-create-javascript-modal.html